# No Sort Order Specified

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When executing code that uses the Google Sheets API to sort a sheet A to Z, I get an error that I don't know how to fix.

> Message[Invalid requests[0].sortRange: No sort order specified.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]

Using this code, it should have created sort order and dimension index, and put it into SortSpec, which was added to SortRange, but it doesn't seem like Google Sheets recognizes that.

```
    List<Data.Request> requests = new List<Data.Request>();  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    Data.SortSpec so = new Data.SortSpec();
    so.SortOrder = "ASCENDING";

    Data.SortSpec di = new Data.SortSpec();
    di.DimensionIndex = 0;

    List<Data.SortSpec> ss = new List<Data.SortSpec>();
    ss.Add(so);
    ss.Add(di);

    var test = new Request()
    {
        SortRange = new SortRangeRequest()
        {
            Range = new GridRange()
            {
                SheetId = 0,
                StartRowIndex = 1
            },
            SortSpecs = ss
        }

    };

    requests.Add(test);

    // TODO: Assign values to desired properties of `requestBody`:
    Data.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest requestBody = new Data.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    requestBody.Requests = requests;

    SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(requestBody, spreadsheetId);

    Data.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = request.Execute();
```

Using debug within Visual Studio, I looked through Autos to see what values request had for SortSpecs, and I found that both values were there.

```
-       [0] {Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.SortSpec}   Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.SortSpec
    DimensionIndex  null    int?
    ETag    null    string
    SortOrder   "ASCENDING" string
-       [1] {Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.SortSpec}   Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.SortSpec
    DimensionIndex  0   int?
    ETag    null    string
    SortOrder   null    string
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer was very simple. Instead of creating seperate sortspecs within the list, you must define dimension index and sort order to the same variable

```
Data.SortSpec so = new Data.SortSpec();
so.SortOrder = "ASCENDING";
so.DimensionIndex = 0;

List<Data.SortSpec> ss = new List<Data.SortSpec>();
ss.Add(so);
```